# Building a toroidal transformer core

Tags: transformer, core, toroidal

I found these stainless steel wires (in diameters 0.3mm to 3mm) being sold in affordable prices.

[image: rolls of ss wire]

My question is whether it's a good idea to wound a thin wire (0.3mm diam.) like the top-right donut shape in this picture :
[image: donut]
Then laminate it with epoxy or something else and use it as a transformer core ?

(It'll be a 220v to 24v transformer)

Comment: What's the permeability of stainless steel and how does it compare with transformer iron/steel?

Comment: It depends on what type of stainless steel the wire is made from - it could be anything from not bad to awful.  Any reason not to use a purpose-designed core?

Comment: @Transistor looking through tables, don't know which steel is the one i should be looking for. The relative permeability range is 40 to 4000.

Comment: I don't either but SS appears to be 20% as good as iron. See https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/permeability-d_1923.html for starters.

Comment: @transistor Thanks for the link. Though I'm aware now that steel in general isn't a good choice for a power transformer core, unfortunately, the available steel is of the worst type (Austenitic stainless steel). Which is no better than air for this use.

Answer (score 2):

Not all stainless steel is magnetic (responds to a magnetic field). Also, a solid iron core causes significant heating because of eddie currents in the bulk conductive material - that is why most cores are made of electrically insulated powders of magnetic material or laminations that are electrically insulated from each other with nanometer thick oxide or phosphate layers.  They are thin to keep the bulk of magnetizable materials (iron, mu-metal, ferrite, etc) as filled as possible (no air gaps). It will be nearly impossible to get a compact mass of the wire when using coils of wire. It is an interesting idea if you would have a wire with square cross-section. If they could be electrically insulated, it might work for you but it all depends on the permeability and how well eddie currents can be abated.